# What is this structure in human brain?

Tags: brain, neuroanatomy

Scientists made a [new image of brain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V5F7snIJ-is).

I wonder, what is this arc (denoted by blue)?

[image: ![enter image description here]

Is it the [caudate nucleus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caudate_nucleus)?

Comment: That blue outline is huge and honestly I can't see what structure you wish to show us with that?

Comment: See at right, it is clean there.

Comment: is that blue line outlining something or did you exactly trace the structure? Could you work with a few arrows with their tips *just* touching the structure of interest? Your blue outline would be a huge structure. It's probably the corpus callosum you are after that lies *within* the blue outline afaik.

Comment: @AliceD see my update please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer**
Based on shape and approximate position, I think it is the corpus callosum.

**Background**
I think it is the *[corpus callosum](https://radiopaedia.org/articles/corpus-callosum)* (Fig. 1). The corpus callosum is approximately 10 cm in length and is C-shaped. It becomes thicker posteriorly, as is also evident in your image. The corpus callosum is a structure consisting of white-matter, [containing about 200 million axons.](http://hubel.med.harvard.edu/book/b34.htm)

[image: ![corpus callosum]
<sup>Fig. 1. Mid-saggital section of the brain showing the corpus callosum. source: [University of Central Florida](http://pegasus.cc.ucf.edu/~Brainmd1/callosum.html)</sup>

I think it is not the caudate nucleus, alhough it has also the curved shape. The caudate is positioned more laterally than the corpus callosum and by the looks of it your picture shows a mid-sagittal section of the brain. The caudate seems to be positioned too far laterally in the brain as far as I can see (Fig. 2).

[image: ![nucleus caudatus]
<sup>Fig.2. Nucleus caudatus. source: [Brain Notes](http://mybrainnotes.com/memory-brain-stress.html)</sup>